# Transactions in spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm confused because when visitService catch visit model then when findAllByDate is invoked then visit appears in database(but only when I use `@Transactional` annotattion) not after `visitRepository.save(visit)`(I've checked in database) moreover even though RuntimeException is thrown added visit doesn't rollback from database(mysql) how to roll it back from database and why `findAllByDate(visit.getDate())` add visit to database

```
 @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Visit save(@Valid Visit visit) {
        logger.info("Inside visitService");
        visit.setPayed(false);
        if (visit.getPrice().intValue() > 1000)
            visit.setDiscount(new BigDecimal(0.05));
        else visit.setDiscount(new BigDecimal(0.00));

        List<Visit> listaWizyt =  findAllByDate(visit.getDate());

        for (int i = 0; i < listaWizyt.size(); ++i)

            System.out.println(listaWizyt.get(i).getId() + " " + listaWizyt.get(i).getDescription() + " " + listaWizyt.get(i).getDate());


        if (listaWizyt.size() > 0){
            logger.info("Throwed exception by visitService");
        throw new RuntimeException("There is already such visit in databse");}
           else
        logger.info("NOT THROWED exception by visitService");

        logger.info("saved by visitService");
        System.out.println("zapisane przez visitService");
         return visitRepository.save(visit);
    }
```

visit repository:

```
public interface VisitRepository extends Repository<Visit, Integer> {


    Visit save(Visit visit) throws DataAccessException;

    List<Visit> findByPetId(Integer petId);

    Visit findById(Integer visitId);

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    List<Visit> findAllByDate(LocalDateTime date);

}
```

Comment: did you configure to enable transaction management in spring?`@EnableTransactionManagement`

Comment: Yes, I added it but still there is not rollback